# Approach guidance: grepping a string between multiple, slightly different delimiters

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk, sed

Assume a 3Kb file that looks like this:

```
PdId1 Unit 1
Model 3244
Status: OK
Advanced Status OK
-----------------------
No errors found
Statistics...
...<arbitrary length values here>...
PdId2 Unit 1
Model 3222
Status: OK
Advanced Status OK
-----------------------
Error Log is as follows <arbitrary values here>
PdId3 Unit 1
Model 3243
Status: OK
Advanced Status OK
-----------------------
No errors found
```

So we can be certain that PdIdn can reliably used as a delimiter, that it's always at the start of a line and that it's always trailing a numebr. I want to parse the text between the delimiter for "No errors found" and if the string is missing, grab the delimiter and the next four lines (grep -A4), glue on an error message and echo the result.

I've been wracking my brain about how to approach this. I'm most comfortable in Bash with grep, but I don't think grep's going to cut it here. I've looked at using split to break the file into pieces, but this seems messy and hard to clean up after processing is done. I started to try to write something in awk / sed, but I don't understand how to split on the delimiters, then go back and parse each result, then break off the *next* piece and parse that.

I apologise for the general nature of this question, but I'm stumped and could use some guidance.

Edit: Technically, PdId isn't a delimiter as much as it's the start of the next record. The number of records is arbitrary.

Edit: We've now got real world data to work with:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PdId: 1
Model Number: WD 1000
Drive Type: SATA
SMART Status: Enable
SMART Health Status: OK
SCT Status Version:                  3
SCT Version (vendor specific):       256 (0x0100)
SCT Support Level:                   1
Device State:                        SMART Off-line Data Collection executing in background (4)
Current Temperature:                    31 Celsius
Power Cycle Min/Max Temperature:     27/31 Celsius
Lifetime    Min/Max Temperature:     16/41 Celsius
Under/Over Temperature Limit Count:   0/0
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine
                    completed without error or no self-test
                    has ever been run.
has ever been run.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 251) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Self-test log structure revision number: 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged


SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
==============================================================================
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME             FLAG    VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED
    WHEN_FAILED  RAW_VALUE
==============================================================================
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate        0x000b  100   100   016    Pre-fail  Always   
        -         0
  2 Throughput_Performance     0x0005  139   139   054    Pre-fail  Offline  
        -         71
  3 Spin_Up_Time               0x0007  169   169   024    Pre-fail  Always   
        -         245 (Average 204)
  4 Start_Stop_Count           0x0012  100   100   000    Old_age   Always   
        -         746
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct      0x0033  100   100   005    Pre-fail  Always   
        -         0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate            0x000b  100   100   067    Pre-fail  Always   
        -         0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance      0x0005  124   124   020    Pre-fail  Offline  
        -         33
  9 Power_On_Hours             0x0012  100   100   000    Old_age   Always   
        -         1181
 10 Spin_Retry_Count           0x0013  100   100   060    Pre-fail  Always   
        -         0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count          0x0032  100   100   000    Old_age   Always   
        -         529
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count    0x0032  100   100   000    Old_age   Always   
        -         751
193 Load_Cycle_Count           0x0012  100   100   000    Old_age   Always   
        -         751
194 Temperature_Celsius        0x0002  193   193   000    Old_age   Always   
        -         31 (Lifetime Min/Max 16/41)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count    0x0032  100   100   000    Old_age   Always   
        -         0
197 Current_Pending_Sector     0x0022  100   100   000    Old_age   Always   
        -         0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable      0x0008  100   100   000    Old_age   Offline  
        -         0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count       0x000a  200   200   000    Old_age   Always   
        -         0

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PdId: 2
Model Number: WD 1000
Drive Type: SATA
SMART Status: Enable
SMART Health Status: OK
SCT Status Version:                  3
SCT Version (vendor specific):       256 (0x0100)
SCT Support Level:                   1
Device State:                        SMART Off-line Data Collection executing in background (4)
Current Temperature:                    31 Celsius
Power Cycle Min/Max Temperature:     27/31 Celsius
Lifetime    Min/Max Temperature:     16/40 Celsius
Under/Over Temperature Limit Count:   0/0
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine
                    completed without error or no self-test
                    has ever been run.
has ever been run.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 246) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Self-test log structure revision number: 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged


SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
==============================================================================
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME             FLAG    VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED
    WHEN_FAILED  RAW_VALUE
==============================================================================
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate        0x000b  100   100   016    Pre-fail  Always   
        -         0
  2 Throughput_Performance     0x0005  139   139   054    Pre-fail  Offline  
        -         72
  3 Spin_Up_Time               0x0007  171   171   024    Pre-fail  Always   
        -         243 (Average 201)
  4 Start_Stop_Count           0x0012  100   100   000    Old_age   Always   
        -         746
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct      0x0033  100   100   005    Pre-fail  Always   
        -         0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate            0x000b  100   100   067    Pre-fail  Always   
        -         0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance      0x0005  124   124   020    Pre-fail  Offline  
        -         33
  9 Power_On_Hours             0x0012  100   100   000    Old_age   Always   
        -         1181
 10 Spin_Retry_Count           0x0013  100   100   060    Pre-fail  Always   
        -         0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count          0x0032  100   100   000    Old_age   Always   
        -         529
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count    0x0032  100   100   000    Old_age   Always   
        -         749
193 Load_Cycle_Count           0x0012  100   100   000    Old_age   Always   
        -         749
194 Temperature_Celsius        0x0002  193   193   000    Old_age   Always   
        -         31 (Lifetime Min/Max 16/40)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count    0x0032  100   100   000    Old_age   Always   
        -         0
197 Current_Pending_Sector     0x0022  100   100   000    Old_age   Always   
        -         0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable      0x0008  100   100   000    Old_age   Offline  
        -         0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count       0x000a  200   200   000    Old_age   Always   
        -         0

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PdId: 3
Model Number: WD 1000
Drive Type: SATA
SMART Status: Enable
SMART Health Status: OK
SCT Status Version:                  3
SCT Version (vendor specific):       256 (0x0100)
SCT Support Level:                   1
Device State:                        SMART Off-line Data Collection executing in background (4)
Current Temperature:                    31 Celsius
Power Cycle Min/Max Temperature:     27/31 Celsius
Lifetime    Min/Max Temperature:     17/40 Celsius
Under/Over Temperature Limit Count:   0/0
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine
                    completed without error or no self-test
                    has ever been run.
has ever been run.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 241) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Self-test log structure revision number: 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged


SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
==============================================================================
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME             FLAG    VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED
    WHEN_FAILED  RAW_VALUE
==============================================================================
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate        0x000b  100   100   016    Pre-fail  Always   
        -         0
  2 Throughput_Performance     0x0005  140   140   054    Pre-fail  Offline  
        -         67
  3 Spin_Up_Time               0x0007  170   170   024    Pre-fail  Always   
        -         234 (Average 213)
  4 Start_Stop_Count           0x0012  100   100   000    Old_age   Always   
        -         748
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct      0x0033  100   100   005    Pre-fail  Always   
        -         0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate            0x000b  100   100   067    Pre-fail  Always   
        -         0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance      0x0005  124   124   020    Pre-fail  Offline  
        -         33
  9 Power_On_Hours             0x0012  100   100   000    Old_age   Always   
        -         1188
 10 Spin_Retry_Count           0x0013  100   100   060    Pre-fail  Always   
        -         0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count          0x0032  100   100   000    Old_age   Always   
        -         529
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count    0x0032  100   100   000    Old_age   Always   
        -         750
193 Load_Cycle_Count           0x0012  100   100   000    Old_age   Always   
        -         750
194 Temperature_Celsius        0x0002  193   193   000    Old_age   Always   
        -         31 (Lifetime Min/Max 17/40)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count    0x0032  100   100   000    Old_age   Always   
        -         0
197 Current_Pending_Sector     0x0022  100   100   000    Old_age   Always   
        -         0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable      0x0008  100   100   000    Old_age   Offline  
        -         0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count       0x000a  200   200   000    Old_age   Always   
        -         0

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PdId: 4
Model Number: WD 1000
Drive Type: SATA
SMART Status: Enable
SMART Health Status: OK
SCT Status Version:                  3
SCT Version (vendor specific):       256 (0x0100)
SCT Support Level:                   1
Device State:                        SMART Off-line Data Collection executing in background (4)
Current Temperature:                    31 Celsius
Power Cycle Min/Max Temperature:     27/31 Celsius
Lifetime    Min/Max Temperature:     15/40 Celsius
Under/Over Temperature Limit Count:   0/0
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine
                    completed without error or no self-test
                    has ever been run.
has ever been run.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 254) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Self-test log structure revision number: 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 165 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
    CR = Command Register [HEX]
    FR = Features Register [HEX]
    SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
    SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
    CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
    CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
    DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
    DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
    ER = Error register [HEX]
    ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 165 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 1176 hours (49 days + 0 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred,
  the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 51 50 b0 ee 81 0d

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  61 80 a8 80 ee 81 40 00      18:38:48.276  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 80 a0 00 ee 81 40 00      18:38:48.276  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 80 98 80 ed 81 40 00      18:38:48.276  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 80 90 00 ed 81 40 00      18:38:48.276  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 80 88 80 ec 81 40 00      18:38:48.275  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED

Error 164 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 1175 hours (48 days + 23 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred,
  the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 51 10 f0 ad 6b 0d  Error: ICRC, ABRT 16 sectors at LBA = 0x0d6badf0 = 225160688

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  35 00 80 80 ad 6b 40 00      18:36:07.145  WRITE DMA EXT
  35 00 80 00 ae 6b 40 00      18:36:07.144  WRITE DMA EXT
  35 00 80 00 ad 6b 40 00      18:36:07.144  WRITE DMA EXT
  35 00 80 80 ab 6b 40 00      18:36:07.139  WRITE DMA EXT
  35 00 80 00 ab 6b 40 00      18:36:07.139  WRITE DMA EXT

Error 163 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 1175 hours (48 days + 23 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred,
  the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 51 f0 10 5e 5d 0d  Error: ICRC, ABRT 240 sectors at LBA = 0x0d5d5e10 = 224222736

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  35 00 80 80 5b 5d 40 00      18:35:47.982  WRITE DMA EXT
  35 00 80 80 5a 5d 40 00      18:35:47.982  WRITE DMA EXT
  35 00 80 00 59 5d 40 00      18:35:47.981  WRITE DMA EXT
  35 00 00 00 58 5d 40 00      18:35:47.979  WRITE DMA EXT
  35 00 30 00 36 5d 40 00      18:35:47.960  WRITE DMA EXT

Error 162 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 1175 hours (48 days + 23 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred,
  the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 51 20 e0 33 19 0d

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  61 80 30 00 33 19 40 00      18:34:50.672  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 80 28 80 33 19 40 00      18:34:50.671  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 80 20 00 34 19 40 00      18:34:50.671  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 00 18 80 34 19 40 00      18:34:50.671  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 80 10 80 36 19 40 00      18:34:50.670  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED

Error 161 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 1133 hours (47 days + 5 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred,
  the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 51 d0 30 dd 3b 0a

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  61 80 38 80 dc 3b 40 00      06:26:51.414  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 80 30 00 df 3b 40 00      06:26:51.413  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 80 28 80 df 3b 40 00      06:26:51.413  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 80 20 00 da 3b 40 00      06:26:51.402  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED
  61 80 18 80 da 3b 40 00      06:26:51.402  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED



SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
==============================================================================
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME             FLAG    VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED
    WHEN_FAILED  RAW_VALUE
==============================================================================
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate        0x000b  100   100   016    Pre-fail  Always   
        -         0
  2 Throughput_Performance     0x0005  139   139   054    Pre-fail  Offline  
        -         73
  3 Spin_Up_Time               0x0007  170   170   024    Pre-fail  Always   
        -         234 (Average 212)
  4 Start_Stop_Count           0x0012  100   100   000    Old_age   Always   
        -         747
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct      0x0033  100   100   005    Pre-fail  Always   
        -         0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate            0x000b  100   100   067    Pre-fail  Always   
        -         0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance      0x0005  124   124   020    Pre-fail  Offline  
        -         33
  9 Power_On_Hours             0x0012  100   100   000    Old_age   Always   
        -         1187
 10 Spin_Retry_Count           0x0013  100   100   060    Pre-fail  Always   
        -         0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count          0x0032  100   100   000    Old_age   Always   
        -         529
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count    0x0032  100   100   000    Old_age   Always   
        -         748
193 Load_Cycle_Count           0x0012  100   100   000    Old_age   Always   
        -         748
194 Temperature_Celsius        0x0002  200   200   000    Old_age   Always   
        -         30 (Lifetime Min/Max 15/40)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count    0x0032  100   100   000    Old_age   Always   
        -         0
197 Current_Pending_Sector     0x0022  100   100   000    Old_age   Always   
        -         0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable      0x0008  100   100   000    Old_age   Offline  
        -         0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count       0x000a  200   200   000    Old_age   Always   
        -         165

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PdId: 5
Model Number: WD 1000
Drive Type: SATA
SMART Status: Enable
SMART Health Status: OK
SCT Status Version:                  3
SCT Version (vendor specific):       256 (0x0100)
SCT Support Level:                   1
Device State:                        SMART Off-line Data Collection executing in background (4)
Current Temperature:                    31 Celsius
Power Cycle Min/Max Temperature:     27/31 Celsius
Lifetime    Min/Max Temperature:     17/40 Celsius
Under/Over Temperature Limit Count:   0/0
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine
                    completed without error or no self-test
                    has ever been run.
has ever been run.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 251) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Self-test log structure revision number: 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged


SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
==============================================================================
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME             FLAG    VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED
    WHEN_FAILED  RAW_VALUE
==============================================================================
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate        0x000b  100   100   016    Pre-fail  Always   
        -         0
  2 Throughput_Performance     0x0005  140   140   054    Pre-fail  Offline  
        -         68
  3 Spin_Up_Time               0x0007  133   133   024    Pre-fail  Always   
        -         289 (Average 282)
  4 Start_Stop_Count           0x0012  100   100   000    Old_age   Always   
        -         748
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct      0x0033  100   100   005    Pre-fail  Always   
        -         0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate            0x000b  100   100   067    Pre-fail  Always   
        -         0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance      0x0005  124   124   020    Pre-fail  Offline  
        -         33
  9 Power_On_Hours             0x0012  100   100   000    Old_age   Always   
        -         1186
 10 Spin_Retry_Count           0x0013  100   100   060    Pre-fail  Always   
        -         0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count          0x0032  100   100   000    Old_age   Always   
        -         529
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count    0x0032  100   100   000    Old_age   Always   
        -         750
193 Load_Cycle_Count           0x0012  100   100   000    Old_age   Always   
        -         750
194 Temperature_Celsius        0x0002  193   193   000    Old_age   Always   
        -         31 (Lifetime Min/Max 17/40)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count    0x0032  100   100   000    Old_age   Always   
        -         0
197 Current_Pending_Sector     0x0022  100   100   000    Old_age   Always   
        -         0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable      0x0008  100   100   000    Old_age   Offline  
        -         0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count       0x000a  200   200   000    Old_age   Always   
        -         0

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PdId: 6
Model Number: WD 1000
Drive Type: SATA
SMART Status: Enable
SMART Health Status: OK
SCT Status Version:                  3
SCT Version (vendor specific):       256 (0x0100)
SCT Support Level:                   1
Device State:                        SMART Off-line Data Collection executing in background (4)
Current Temperature:                    30 Celsius
Power Cycle Min/Max Temperature:     27/30 Celsius
Lifetime    Min/Max Temperature:     17/40 Celsius
Under/Over Temperature Limit Count:   0/0
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine
                    completed without error or no self-test
                    has ever been run.
has ever been run.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 243) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Self-test log structure revision number: 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged


SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
==============================================================================
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME             FLAG    VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED
    WHEN_FAILED  RAW_VALUE
==============================================================================
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate        0x000b  100   100   016    Pre-fail  Always   
        -         0
  2 Throughput_Performance     0x0005  139   139   054    Pre-fail  Offline  
        -         72
  3 Spin_Up_Time               0x0007  130   130   024    Pre-fail  Always   
        -         294 (Average 287)
  4 Start_Stop_Count           0x0012  100   100   000    Old_age   Always   
        -         748
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct      0x0033  100   100   005    Pre-fail  Always   
        -         0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate            0x000b  100   100   067    Pre-fail  Always   
        -         0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance      0x0005  124   124   020    Pre-fail  Offline  
        -         33
  9 Power_On_Hours             0x0012  100   100   000    Old_age   Always   
        -         1186
 10 Spin_Retry_Count           0x0013  100   100   060    Pre-fail  Always   
        -         0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count          0x0032  100   100   000    Old_age   Always   
        -         529
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count    0x0032  100   100   000    Old_age   Always   
        -         751
193 Load_Cycle_Count           0x0012  100   100   000    Old_age   Always   
        -         751
194 Temperature_Celsius        0x0002  200   200   000    Old_age   Always   
        -         30 (Lifetime Min/Max 17/40)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count    0x0032  100   100   000    Old_age   Always   
        -         0
197 Current_Pending_Sector     0x0022  100   100   000    Old_age   Always   
        -         0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable      0x0008  100   100   000    Old_age   Offline  
        -         0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count       0x000a  200   200   000    Old_age   Always   
        -         0
```

Comment: So what part of your sample input do you need to select?

Comment: So if you concatenate the first sample with the second one, you've got a basic sample data file. On any record that has "ATA Error Count" or is missing "No Errors Logged", I want to return the next five lines after a 'PdId' as well as the "ATA Error Count" string. I don't think awk will cut it here. Maybe Python?

Answer (score 0):

Read line by line, collect into an accumulator the lines you want, print the accumulated lines when you see the trigger message (otherwise just start over and overwrite the accumulator when you see the start of the next record).

We use `a` as the accumulator and the helper variable `n` to keep track of how many lines to accumulate:

```
awk '/^PdId: [1-9][0-9]*/ { a=$0; n=4; next }
    n { --n; a=a "\n" $ 0; next }
    /No Errors Logged/ { print a }' file
```

Comment: This is very tidy! But it gives all the records with No Errors Logged. We want the records *without* No Errors Logged. Can this be modified?

Comment: This seems to work: `awk '/^PdId: [1-9][0-9]*/ { a=$0; n=4; next } n { --n; a=a "\n" $0; next } /^ATA Error Count*/ { ata_err=$0; print a "\n" ata_err }' file` I'm going to try to figure out how to grab a few lines after the "ATA Error Count".

Answer (score 0):

Put the following into an executable awk file:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {no_errs=1}

c > 0 {a[c++]=$0}

/^----------/ {
    logAnyErrors()
    ata_err=""
    no_errs=0
    c=1 
    delete a
}   

/^No Errors Logged/ {no_errs=1}
/^ATA Error Count:/ {ata_err=$0}

function logAnyErrors() {
    if( ata_err!="" || !no_errs) {
        for(i=1;i<=5;i++) print a[i]
        if( ata_err!="" ) print ata_err
        print "--" # separator
    }
}

END { logAnyErrors() }
```

Your data actually has a delimiter of "^------------------"... before each `PdId`.

The breakdown:

- Start off assuming no errors in the BEGIN block
- add each record line to an array called `a` with a line counter `c`
- Whenever a new record section occurs call `logAnyErrors()` and reset counters
- In `logAnyErrors()`, if there are ATA or other errors, print the first 5 lines of the record and a delimiter similar to what I think `grep -A4` would output.
- At the end, log any errors in the final record.

When I put this into an executable file called `awko` and run like `awko data` I get the following output:

```
PdId: 4
Model Number: WD 1000
Drive Type: SATA
SMART Status: Enable
SMART Health Status: OK
ATA Error Count: 165 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
----------------
```

It's possible that the `delete a` line is non-conforming for some awks.  Works on my mac.  It's not necessary unless you want to print out more information in each block when errors occur(since the first 5 lines will always be overwritten).